# unable to install ffmpeg on raspbian

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, streaming, video-streaming, raspbian

I'm trying this [guide](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/blogs/streaming-live-to-youtube-and-facebook-using-raspberry-pi-camera/969a7932d47d42a79ba72c81da4d9b66) to stream my Pi camera (running on raspberry pi 3b with raspbian) to YouTube live.
when i try to install ffmpeg, I'm getting this message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt $ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavdevice56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavfilter5 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavformat56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried a lot of tutorials but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Isn't `libav-tools` on raspian? Everything equal, just a change in name...

Comment: it is. That's why i cant understand what's going wrong

Comment: nothing fancy. https://wiki.debian.org/ffmpeg on debian ffmpeg is equal but with the name avconv. So give the command you want, with the same options but instead of ffmpeg call it avconf. You can fix with an alias in your bashrc file: `alias ffmpeg="avconf"`, or by making a symbolic link in your /usr/bin from avconf to ffmpeg

Comment: i tried doing as you told, and still its not working. i have tried to install libav-tools and got this massege:
"libav-tools : Depends: ffmpeg (= 10:2.6.9-dmo1) but 7:3.2.5-1~bpo8+1 is to be installedBreaks: ffmpeg (< 10:2.0.2~) but 7:3.2.5-1~bpo8+1 is to be installed"

Comment: Before install libav tools try a apt-get install -f

Comment: got the exact same massage once more.

Comment: MH. Try with a apt update, then apt install -f. Finally install avconv.